# Ежесекундное обновление записи

Tags: javascript

Мой код:

```
function timer(intr){
            sg.innerHTML = intr;
            intr = intr - 1;
            setTimeout(function() {
            timer(intr);
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Ошибка: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`
Мне нужно, что ты функция `timer()` ежесекундно использовалась заново. В принципе, я понимаю, почему появляется эта ошибка, но как ее исправить - не знаю, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: `timer(intr);` нужен, что бы по исчению одной секунды эта функция начиналась выполняться заново.

Comment: Приведенный код не может вызвать данную ошибку, так как setTimeout не вызывает функцию сразу, а следовательно не забивает стек

Comment: А в каком браузере возникает ошибка (желательно с версией)? Хотим у себя повторить. Код и правда выглядит как рабочий. Ошибка может возникнуть разве что если "баг" в браузере, или есть что-то что не отражено в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О, наконец то на stackoverflow вопрос про stackoverflow)
Для того чтоб разорвать [порочную цепь рекурсии](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA), уберите из setTimeout анонимную функцию -

```js
function timer(intr){
    sg.innerHTML = intr;
    intr = intr - 1;
    setTimeout(timer, 1/*000*/, intr);
}

timer(1000000);
```

```html
<div id=sg></div>
```

Comment: Но в коде в вопросе ж нет рекурсии

Comment: @Grundy, однако в коде таки рекурсия есть) Просто мы этот код не увидели.

Comment: @vp_arth, поэтому стоит либо закрыть вопрос как _не воспроизводится_, либо закрыть как _нужно [mcve]_ :)

Comment: @Darth Пожалуйста, напишите автору вопроса, что Ваш код ничем принципиально не отличается от его кода, и этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения к устранению описываемой ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

В коде вопроса все правильно. Ошибка где-то в другом месте.

```js
var sg = document.getElementById("sg");

function timer(intr) {
  sg.innerHTML = intr;
  intr = intr - 1;
  setTimeout(function() {
    timer(intr);
  }, 1000);
}
timer(100);
```

```html
<div id="sg"></div>
```

Comment: Возможно в стеке накапливаются анонимные ф-ции и уборщик мусора в некоторых браузерах не успевает их чистить.

Comment: Или как вариант размер стека у вас больше чем 100)

Comment: @nick_n_a, Darth - Нет, невозможно. Вам сюда: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: О чём вы тут? setTimeout же вызывает функцию на чистом стеке..

Comment: Имеется ввиду не стек, а куча. Анонимная функция добавляется в кучу. Если её удаление из кучи идет медленнее чем добавление - то место там закончится. Просто для стека и кучи в отдельных случаях даётся один кусок памяти, для кучи "спереди" а для стека "сзади". Поэтому эти понятия иногда перепутаны.

Comment: Как только там закончится место(забьётся функциями, вы серьёзно?) - gc его освободит. Что за бред.